# A special kind of bst file for a custom bibliography file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to automatize the handling of my bibliographical references once for all, and to achieve this, I would like to use `bibtex`. I am aware of the existence of various `bst` files, for various styles of bibliographies: numerical labels, alphanumerical labels *etc*, but I would like to mix them, and to keep certain bibliographical references always in the same order, and always on the top of my references lists. But I don't know how to do it. I would like the output to look like the bibliography produced by the following LaTeX source code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{100}
\addtolength{\leftmargin}{0.2in} % sets up alignment with the following line.
\setlength{\itemindent}{-0.2in}
\bibitem[EGA]{EGA} {\sc A. Grothendieck} et {\sc J. Dieudonn\'e}, \emph{\'El\'ements de g\'eom\'etrie alg\'ebrique, (Publ. Math. I.H.E.S.}, tomes $4$, $8$, $11$, $17$, $20$, $24$, $28$, $32$, $1960$-$1967$).
\bibitem[EGA I]{EGA1} {\sc A. Grothendieck} et {\sc J. Dieudonn\'e}, \emph{\'El\'ements de g\'eom\'etrie alg\'ebrique, I. Le langage des sch\'emas, (Publ. Math. I.H.E.S.}, tome $4$, $1960$).
\bibitem[EGA II]{EGA2} {\sc A. Grothendieck} et {\sc J. Dieudonn\'e}, \emph{\'El\'ements de g\'eom\'etrie alg\'ebrique, II. \'Etude globale \'el\'ementaire de quelques classes de morphismes, (Publ. Math. I.H.E.S.}, tome $8$, $1961$).
\bibitem[EGA III.1]{EGA31} {\sc A. Grothendieck} et {\sc J. Dieudonn\'e}, \emph{\'El\'ements de g\'eom\'etrie alg\'ebrique, III.1. \'Etude cohomologique des faisceaux coh\'erents (Premi\`ere partie), (Publ. Math. I.H.E.S.}, tome $11$, $1961$).
\bibitem[EGA III.2]{EGA32} {\sc A. Grothendieck} et {\sc J. Dieudonn\'e}, \emph{\'El\'ements de g\'eom\'etrie alg\'ebrique, III.2. \'Etude cohomologique des faisceaux coh\'erents (Seconde partie), (Publ. Math. I.H.E.S.}, tome $17$, $1963$).
\bibitem[EGA IV.1]{EGA41} {\sc A. Grothendieck} et {\sc J. Dieudonn\'e}, \emph{\'El\'ements de g\'eom\'etrie alg\'ebrique, IV.1. \'Etude locale des sch\'emas et des morphismes de sch\'emas (Premi\`ere partie), (Publ. Math. I.H.E.S.}, tome $20$, $1964$).
\bibitem[EGA IV.2]{EGA42} {\sc A. Grothendieck} et {\sc J. Dieudonn\'e}, \emph{\'El\'ements de g\'eom\'etrie alg\'ebrique, IV.2. \'Etude locale des sch\'emas et des morphismes de sch\'emas (Seconde partie), (Publ. Math. I.H.E.S.}, tome $20$, $1964$).
\bibitem[EGA IV.3]{EGA43} {\sc A. Grothendieck} et {\sc J. Dieudonn\'e}, \emph{\'El\'ements de g\'eom\'etrie alg\'ebrique, IV.3. \'Etude locale des sch\'emas et des morphismes de sch\'emas (Troisi\`eme partie), (Publ. Math. I.H.E.S.}, tome $28$, $1966$).
\bibitem[EGA IV.4]{EGA44} {\sc A. Grothendieck} et {\sc J. Dieudonn\'e}, \emph{\'El\'ements de g\'eom\'etrie alg\'ebrique, IV.4. \'Etude locale des sch\'emas et des morphismes de sch\'emas (Quatri\`eme partie), (Publ. Math. I.H.E.S.}, tome $32$, $1967$).
\bibitem[1]{1}{Some less important reference}
\end{thebibliography}
```

whose output looks like this :

[image]

The group of "EGA" references (that is, all references except the last one) is the list of references that I want to keep in this order (labels appear to be already sorted in alphabetical order, but it could not be the case) and always on top of my bibliography.

Comment: Right now, your whole bibliography is set up by hand, not by having a database around and let a package make the work. `biblatex` is the newest guy in town, and does everything all the multiple bib-specific packages can do with (almost) the blink of an eye. You can define specific rules for sorting and give additional `presort` or `sorttitle` fields if you want something special.

Comment: The sorting is easily achieved via biblatex, but since all the 'example' entries you give are identical in form, it is not very helpful for providing advice about what style to use (and whether it needs a little or a lot of tweaking).

Comment: @jon As I wrote : "the group of "EGA" references (that is, all references except the last one) is the list of references that I want to keep in this order (labels appear to be already sorted in alphabetical order, but it could not be the case) and always on top of my bibliography"

Comment: @Johannes_B Could you pls point to an example in biblatex achieving this ? Thx

Comment: Take a look at the `biblatex` documentation, § 3.6.7, ‘Bibliography categories’,p. 79 and § 3.11.4, ‘Subdivided bibliographies’, p.109–111.

Comment: Indeed: the placement and labels are the easy parts of constructing a bibliography style in `biblatex`: it's the actual formatting of the output of (all) the entry types that is tricky. With only one entry type shown, this question is impossible to answer properly.

Comment: Off-topic: `\sc` was deprecated when LaTeX 2.09 retired to a well-deserved home for elderly formats 20+ years ago. `\scshape` or `\textsc{}` should be used for all LaTeX 2e documents.